# Django send_mail with £ sign. Not displaying correctly in outlook

Tags: python, django, email

I am using django to send emails using the built in send_mail function.

The function to send the email looks something like:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.template import loader
from django.core.mail import send_mail
#stuff to get user
context = {'user':user}
subject = loader.render_to_string('subjecttemplate.txt', context)
# Email subject cannot contain newlines
subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
message = loader.render_to_string('emailtemplate.html', context)
send_mail(subject, message, None, [user.email])
```

And the template `emailtemplate.html` looks something like

```
Dear {{ user.first_name }},

The price is £20.

etc.
```

Viewed in most email clients, this works as I intend. However in microsoft outlook, the pound symbol in the message displays as �.

I'm assuming this is some kind of encoding mismatch issue but I'm not sure how to fix it. Do I need to declare somewhere in an email header or something that the email will be unicode?

UPDATE

I'm still no further along with this really. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715071/php-mail-with-utf-8-encoding-displays-incorrectly-in-microsoft-mail-clients) older PHP question which seems to be solved by removing the quotation marks around the charset in the headers. This is built in to the `message` method of the [EmailMessage](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/mail/message.py) class in Django so I wrote a quick custom class (see below) and tried sending my emails using that but it seems to make no difference.

```
import re

from django.core.mail.message import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.conf import settings


class CustomEmailMultiAlternatives(EmailMultiAlternatives):
    """
    Customisation of built in Django email class to adjust header so that no
    quotes around charset
    """
    def message(self):
        msg = super(CustomEmailMultiAlternatives, self).message()
        charset = self.encoding or settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET
        if charset == 'utf-8':
            CT_header = msg.get('Content-Type')
            new_CT_header = re.sub(r'(charset=)(")(.*)(")', r'\1\3', CT_header)
            msg.replace_header('Content-Type', new_CT_header)
        return msg
```

Comment: just a shot in the dark: what happens if you encode the string to UTF-8? python3 does this by default but python2 does not. perhaps, default encoding is something else in outlook?

Comment: The message arrives with a header `Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"` so I think that it is already telling outlook it is UTF-8?

Comment: It seems outlook does not encode to UTF-8 by default unfortunately. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/278134